# Difference between clang and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

I used both of these compilers in different projects.

How they are different in terms of code processing and output generations? For example both `gcc` and `clang` has `-O2` options for optimization. Are they operating the same way (high level) in terms of optimizing code? I did a little test , for example if I have the following code:

```
int foo(int num) {
    if(num % 2 == 1)
        return num * num;
    else
        return num * num +1;  
}
```

the following are the output assemblies with clang and gcc with -O2:

```
----gcc 5.3.0-----                              ----clang 3.8.0----
foo(int):                                       foo(int):
        movl    %edi, %edx                              movl    %edi, %eax
        shrl    $31, %edx                               shrl    $31, %eax
        leal    (%rdi,%rdx), %eax                       addl    %edi, %eax
        andl    $1, %eax                                andl    $-2, %eax
        subl    %edx, %eax                              movl    %edi, %ecx
        cmpl    $1, %eax                                subl    %eax, %ecx
        je      .L5                                     imull   %edi, %edi
        imull   %edi, %edi                              cmpl    $1, %ecx
        leal    1(%rdi), %eax                           setne   %al
        ret                                             movzbl  %al, %eax
.L5:                                                    addl    %edi, %eax
        movl    %edi, %eax                              retq
        imull   %edi, %eax
        ret
```

as it can be seen the output has different instructions. So my question is does one of them has advantage over another in different projects?

Comment: You could improve your code by writing `int foo(int num) { return num * num + ~num & 1; }` instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl: great point, that [makes much better code](https://godbolt.org/g/Y1RZuj), but you need parens `int foo(int num) { return num * num + (~num & 1); }` because `&` has lower precedence than * and +.  Also, that does have different behaviour for negative numbers.  In C, `-1 % 2` is `-1`, so the if is false.  gcc's code accounts for this if you write `n*n + (n%2)`.

Comment: @FUZxxl thanks for the note, it is just a simple test to see which compilers output what

Comment: @PeterCordes Right. You are of course correct.

Comment: @FUZxxl `return num * num + ~num & 1;` are you kidding me?  That code is confusing, you made a mistake in a single line, original code is safer for larger pool of people to maintain.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. And no.

This is like asking whether an Audi car has an advantage over a Mercedes car. Like them, the two compilers are two different projects aiming to do the same thing. In some cases, `gcc` will emit better code, in others it will be `clang`.

When you need to know, you have to compile your code with both and then measure it.

There is an argument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187414/clang-vs-gcc-which-produces-better-binaries) and somewhat less related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205858/clang-vs-gcc-for-my-linux-development-project).

Answer (score 17):

In this case the Clang output is better, because it does not branch; instead it loads the value of `num % 2 == 1` to `al` the code generated by gcc uses jumps. If `num` is expected to be even/odd with 50 % chances, and with no repeating patterns, the code generated by GCC will be [susceptible to branch prediction failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array).

---

However you can make the code well-behaved on GCC as well by doing

```
int foo(int num) {
    return num * num + (num % 2 != 1);
}
```

Even more so, as it seems that your algorithm is really defined for unsigned numbers only, you should use `unsigned int` (they're different for negative numbers) - actually you get a major speedup by using `unsigned int` for the argument, as now GCC/Clang can optimize `num % 2` to `num & 1`:

```
unsigned int foo(unsigned int num) {
    return num * num + (num % 2 != 1);
}
```

The resulting code generated by `gcc -O2`

```
movl    %edi, %edx
imull   %edi, %edi
andl    $1, %edx
xorl    $1, %edx
leal    (%rdi,%rdx), %eax
ret
```

is much better than the code for your original function generated by either compiler. Thus a compiler does not matter as much as does a programmer who knows what he's doing.